# Rails plugin with a different version of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a rails 3 app, and I want to use a plugin that requires rails_generator, which is no longer available in rails 3. Can I have the plugin run with Rails 2, and my app run with Rails 3?

EDIT:
I asked on IRC (#rubyonrails) and the answer is no :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3 has a generator.  Depending on the rest of the plugin though you might have to make modifications to make it Rails 3 compatible.  You can run the generator like this:

```
rails generate ...
```

Comment: The plugin has a .rake file with `require 'rails_generator'` in it, so I get an error when I run the rake command.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the rake task then and seeing if you can modify it to work with Rails3. If that's the only issue with the plugin being Rails3 compatible you might also just want to contact the author and see if they have plans for Rails3 compatibility.